# Compare data between 2 sheets and move data to sheet3

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a solution for my case. Right now i have a file with 3 sheets where i have data in 2 sheets. In first sheet "sheet1", i have raw data with many rows (~10k rows of data) and 10 columns (A:J), in second sheet "sheet2" (~1k-8krows of data) i have the same 10 columns like "sheet1" (A:J) with data only on column "C". The code i used is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyDuplicates()
    MsgBox "Procesul a inceput. Daca nu se regasesc date in 'Sheet3', " & _
           "inseamna ca datele din coloana 'C - Sheet2' nu se regasesc in 'Sheet1'"
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long, r3 As Long
    Dim ar As Variant, i As Long
    
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    ws3.Cells.Clear

    lr1 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lr2 = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ws1.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    ws2.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    ' dictionar sheet2 coloana C
    Dim dict, key As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For r = 1 To lr2
        key = Trim(ws2.Cells(r, "C"))
        If Len(key) > 0 Then
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                dict(key) = dict(key) & ";" & r
            Else
                dict.Add key, r
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    r3 = 1 ' Sheet3
    ' scaneaza datele din Sheet1 daca se regasesc in Sheet2
    For r = 1 To lr1
        key = Trim(ws1.Cells(r, "C"))
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            ' functie copiere/stergere - datele regasite in urma scanarii le copiaza in Sheet3 urmand a fi sterse din Sheet1
            ar = Split(dict(key), ";")
            For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
                ws1.Range("A" & r).Resize(1, 10).Copy ws3.Range("A" & r3) ' A:J
                ws1.Range("A" & r).Rows.Delete
                r3 = r3 + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Proces finalizat cu succes."
End Sub
```

My script compare data from "sheet1" to data inserted in column "C" from "sheet2" and if match, copy rows in "sheet3" from "sheet1" then delete the rows matched from "sheet1" + first row (table header). How can i skip the first row (table header) from delete function on "sheet1?

Edit:
I added screenshots with "sheet1" and "sheet2"
[sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPQB6.jpg)
[sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xijy.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be enough to start the code in row2

So instead of
For r = 1 To lr1
put
For r = 2 To lr1

Comment: after i modified r = 2, the code don't work well, he didnt copy all the rows matched in sheet2.

Comment: did he leave out just one, every second, ???

Comment: maybe you changed For r = 1 To lr2 - that would be wrong, change For r = 1 To lr1

Comment: thanks for your time Max, can we move to chat room? still not working well after modify.

Comment: i found the solution by adding another script to match data from sheet3 and delete rows from sheet1. thanks Max for your time again.